# Error in angular js controller for pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, pagination

I am coding in angular js for client side pagination.

Starting in other question here about pagination, I've transformed the code to this but doesn't work.

What is wrong?

```
myapp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Events) {
  $scope.mydata = [];

  Events.query(function(data) {
    $scope.mydata = data;
  });


  $scope.get = function (offset, limit) {
    return $scope.mydata.slice( offset, offset+limit );
  };

  $scope.count = function () {
    return $scope.mydata.length;
  };

  $scope.numPerPage = 5;
  $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.count / $scope.numPerPage);
  $scope.currentPage = 1;

  $scope.setPage = function () {
    $scope.data = $scope.get( ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage,   $scope.numPerPage );
  };

  $scope.$watch( 'currentPage', $scope.setPage );
});
```

$scope.get and $scope.count don't work. Events.query is getting all JSON data from service in array format.

I can test this code in chrome angular js extension.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{mydata.length}}` in your html instead of the `$scope.count` function.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: okey till i get more reputation can i leave the answer?so i have more clarification to answer it correctly ?